# How are NFTs stored in the bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, taproot, storage, ordinals, nft

I'm new to bitcoin and am looking into how NFTs are stored into the blockchain. I saw somewhere that Taproot Script-Path Spend Scripts is where NFT data is stored but I'm not sure how. Can someone please explain it? I'm more specifically looking for how it's stored in the blockchain, but what is stored.

Comment: Hi Mark, this site focuses on the technologies supporting the bitcoin currency. The inner workings of schemes used by people to dump arbitrary data on the blockchain do not seem relevant in that scope. I suggest that you peruse the ordinals documentation instead.